# Merge two CSV file into JSON

Tags: python, json, csv

I want to combine two CSV files and convert it into JSON. The difficult thing is that the same column in two files are not unique in rows, like this:

```
gpo_full.csv:
Date           hearing_sub_type   Old_ID   witnesses
January,1997   Oversight          22       Babbitt
June,2000      General            21       Blitzer
January,1997   General            23       Alldridge
April,2001     Oversight          25       Michael 
June,2000      Oversight          24       Bruce

CAP_cols.csv:
majortopic   id     Chamber   subtopic   Date
21           79846  1         2103       January,1997
4            79847  2         705        June,2000
13           79848  1         1802       May,2001
7            79849  2         201        June,2000
21           79850  1         401        January,1997
```

The output I want should be like:

```
 [{
"Date": "January,1997",
"GPO": [{
    "hearing_sub_type": "Oversight",
    "Old_ID": "22",
    "witnesses": "Babbitt"
}, {
    "hearing_sub_type": "General",
    "Old_ID": "23",
    "witnesses": "Alldridge"
}]
"CAP": [{
    "majortopic": "21",
    "id": "79846",
    "Chamber": "1"
    "subtopic": "2103"
}, {
    "majortopic": "21",
    "id": "79850",
    "Chamber": "1"
    "subtopic": "401"
}]
},
and similar for others]
```

If there is no matching data like April,2001 in G.csv and May,2001 in C.csv, the format will be the same but value is none like this:

```
[{
"Date": "April,2001",
"GPO": [{
    "hearing_sub_type": None,
    "Old_ID": None,
    "witnesses": None
}]
"CAP": [{
    "majortopic": None,
    "id": None,
    "Chamber": None, 
    "subtopic": None
}]
},
and similar for others]
```

The code I wrote is

```
GPO = open("gpo_full.csv", "r")
CAP = open("CAP_cols.csv", "r")

jsonfile = open('datamerge.json', 'w')

gporeader = csv.DictReader(GPO)
capreader = csv.DictReader(CAP)

output = []
for gporow in gporeader:
    output.append(gporow["Date"])
    gporow["CAP"] = []
    gporow["GPO"] = []
    if gporow["Date"] in output:
        gporow["GPO"].append(gporow)
    CAP.seek(0)
    for caprow in capreader:
        if (gporow["Date"] == caprow["Date"]):
            gporow["CAP"].append(caprow)
print(output)
json.dump(output, jsonfile, sort_keys=True)
```

It does not work. More specifically, I do not know how to extract date as a key and delete them in GPO and CAP. 
I am really appreciated that martineau draws a whole picture for me!

Comment: "Does not work" is an inadequate description of what's wrong. Does it give you the wrong output? If so, how does it differ from your expectations? If it throws an error, what is the error? Have you done any [debugging](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) before asking here? Please take the [tour], read [ask], [on-topic](/help/on-topic), the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and [how much research?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953) Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guessing at what you meant by "It does not work" by examining your code and desired output, I think I've been able to write some code that does.

First here's the data I used where `»` right-guillemet characters are being used to represent tab `'\t'` characters — in other words you have tab-delimited CSV files which must be specified when reading them with `csv.DictReader` because the default is for there to be commas between the values.

#### Input files

`gpo_full.csv`:

```
Date»hearing_sub_type»Old_ID»witnesses
January,1997»Oversight»22»Babbitt
June,2000»General»21»Blitzer
January,1997»General»23»Alldridge
April,2001»Oversight»25»Michael
June,2000»Oversight»24»Bruce
```

`CAP_cols.csv`:

```
majortopic»id»Chamber»subtopic»Date
21»79846»1»2103»January,1997
4»79847»2»705»June,2000
13»79848»1»1802»May,2001
7»79849»2»201»June,2000
21»79850»1»401»January,1997
```

#### Code:

The most significant change made was to make `output` a dictionary subclass whose keys are dates (see caveat noted below about them) each associated with a *nested* dictionary that contains its own pair of `"CAP"` and `"GPO"` lists. Doing so made it easy to detect whether date had ever been encountered before, and initialize the nested dictionary for it — which does the searching through the other CSV file for matching dates (and making that automatic is why a dictionary *subclass* was defined and used).

**✶**Something I think is worth mentioning is that "rewinding" a CSV file via a `file.seek(0)` in order to re-read the rows of data in it doesn't work. They must instead be closed, reopened, and have their `csv.DictReader` recreated. This is at least partially because—in this case—the files have that special header row at the beginning defining the names of their fields.

A **caveat** I'd like to mention is that since the date fields are in a "month,year" format which cannot be used for sorting them chronologically because they will be compared lexicographically as strings, not numerically — i.e. `June,2021` would be considered to come *before* `December,2001` — which is the main reason I've disabled sorting. That can be fixed, but it's not the primary topic of your question.

```
import csv
import json
from pprint import pprint


class OutputDict(dict):
    """ Dictionary subclass to create initial entry for each date. """
    def __init__(self, cap_filename):
        super().__init__()  # Base class initialization.
        self.cap_filename = cap_filename

    def __missing__(self, date):
        """ Initialize entry for a date when it's first encountered. """
        self[date] = {'Date': date, 'GPO': [], 'CAP': []}

        # Scan cap csv file for matching dates - occurs once per unique date added.
        with open(self.cap_filename) as cap_file:  # Add matches from other CSV file.
            cap_reader = csv.DictReader(cap_file, delimiter='\t')
            for cap_row in cap_reader:
                if date == cap_row['Date']:
                    del cap_row['Date']
                    self[date]['CAP'].append(cap_row)

        # If there weren't any matching dates, create and add an empty row.
        if not self[date]['CAP']:  # No matching CAP dates?
            cap_row = {field: None for field in cap_reader.fieldnames if field != 'Date'}
            self[date]['CAP'].append(cap_row)

        return self[date]


# Add all the dates in the gpo_full.csv file to an output dictionary.
output = OutputDict('CAP_cols.csv')  # Automatically add matching dates in CAP_cols file.
with open('gpo_full.csv') as gpo_file:
    gpo_reader = csv.DictReader(gpo_file, delimiter='\t')
    for gpo_row in gpo_reader:
        date = gpo_row.pop('Date')
        output[date]['GPO'].append(gpo_row)

# Add any dates in CAP_cols.csv that weren't in gpo_full.csv file.
with open('CAP_cols.csv') as cap_file:
    cap_reader = csv.DictReader(cap_file, delimiter='\t')
    for cap_row in cap_reader:
        date = cap_row.pop('Date')
        if date not in output:  # Create entry for it with a null gpo row.
            gpo_row = {field: None for field in gpo_reader.fieldnames if field != 'Date'}
            output[date]['GPO'].append(gpo_row)  # Automatically adds cap_row.

output = list(output.values())  # Only want a list of the values.
#pprint(output, sort_dicts=0)  # Show what's going into JSON file.

with open('datamerge.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(output, json_file, indent=4, sort_keys=False)

print('-Fini-')
```

#### Results

Here's what it puts into the `datamerge.json` file:

```
[
    {
        "Date": "January,1997",
        "GPO": [
            {
                "hearing_sub_type": "Oversight",
                "Old_ID": "22",
                "witnesses": "Babbitt"
            },
            {
                "hearing_sub_type": "General",
                "Old_ID": "23",
                "witnesses": "Alldridge"
            }
        ],
        "CAP": [
            {
                "majortopic": "21",
                "id": "79846",
                "Chamber": "1",
                "subtopic": "2103"
            },
            {
                "majortopic": "21",
                "id": "79850",
                "Chamber": "1",
                "subtopic": "401"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Date": "June,2000",
        "GPO": [
            {
                "hearing_sub_type": "General",
                "Old_ID": "21",
                "witnesses": "Blitzer"
            },
            {
                "hearing_sub_type": "Oversight",
                "Old_ID": "24",
                "witnesses": "Bruce"
            }
        ],
        "CAP": [
            {
                "majortopic": "4",
                "id": "79847",
                "Chamber": "2",
                "subtopic": "705"
            },
            {
                "majortopic": "7",
                "id": "79849",
                "Chamber": "2",
                "subtopic": "201"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Date": "April,2001",
        "GPO": [
            {
                "hearing_sub_type": "Oversight",
                "Old_ID": "25",
                "witnesses": "Michael"
            }
        ],
        "CAP": [
            {
                "majortopic": null,
                "id": null,
                "Chamber": null,
                "subtopic": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Date": "May,2001",
        "GPO": [
            {
                "hearing_sub_type": null,
                "Old_ID": null,
                "witnesses": null
            }
        ],
        "CAP": [
            {
                "majortopic": "13",
                "id": "79848",
                "Chamber": "1",
                "subtopic": "1802"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: I really appreciated your code! You give me a good sense of converting CSV to JSON!!! THANKS A LOT!!!

Comment: @whitneyl: That's good to hear and you're welcome. This is actually a somewhat challenging problem that I've enjoyed working on (and optimizing).